# Scrape data from specific maps website with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

[image: The Table:]I'm trying to get data from a site with maps on real estate prices.
The problem is that I can't access the data with BS.
I looked for answers on the Internet but I didn't find it, probably because it's a specific site.

When I put the map on "real estate" mode I can move on the map and select a house. When I click on the house I get data on the transaction prices of the house and other houses in the area using a table that appears on the screen.
I can't get to the data of the table and take it with BS.

c in the location and z is the real estate = NADLAN

```
URL = "https://www.govmap.gov.il/?c=180570.51,667032.28&z=10&lay=NADLAN"
r = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content , "html.parser")
```

Comment: You have to use `Selenium`, because the content is being created dynamically and isn't available with `BeautifulSoup`.

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded from external URL via Json, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. You can use next example how to load the data into a DataFrame:

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = "https://ags.govmap.gov.il/Identify/GetDealsByStreetCodes"

payload = {
    "Extent": {
        "xmax": 180658.3,
        "xmin": 180633.8,
        "ymax": 667096.5,
        "ymin": 667078.19,
    },
    "StreetCodes": [50000820],
}

data = requests.post(url, json=payload).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

df = pd.DataFrame(data["data"])
print(df.head().to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| centroid | extent | DEALDATESTRING | DEALDATE | ADDRESS | NEIGHBORHOOD | NEIGHBORHOODID | STREENNAME | GUSHHELKATAT | ASSETTYPE | ROOMNUM | FLOOR | ASSETMETER | DEALS_DEALAMOUNT | DEALTYPE | PROJECTNAME | STREETCODE | WKT | POLYGONID | CITY | CITYID | OBJECTID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {'y': 667044.31, 'x': 180596.09, 'geometryType': 'point'} | {'xmin': 180633.8, 'ymin': 667078.19, 'xmax': 180658.3, 'ymax': 667096.5} | 27/02/2022 | 2022-02-27T00:00:00 | הרב צירלסון 39 | הצפון החדש החלק הצפוני | 6.521e+07 | הרב צירלסון | 6212-1245-23 |  | 4 | רביעית | 88 | 5.745e+06 |  |  | 5.00008e+07 | POLYGON (( 180596.09000000 667044.31000000, 180612.80000000 667046.38000000, 180612.09000000 667052.31000000, 180618.20000000 667053.12000000, 180614.00000000 667085.81000000, 180607.59000000 667084.88000000, 180611.50000000 667054.19000000, 180595.09000000 667052.12000000, 180596.09000000 667044.31000000)) | 52333507 | תל אביב -יפו | 5000 | 109293 |
| {'y': 666777.19, 'x': 180658.41, 'geometryType': 'point'} | {'xmin': 180633.8, 'ymin': 667078.19, 'xmax': 180658.3, 'ymax': 667096.5} | 19/12/2021 | 2021-12-19T00:00:00 | הרב צירלסון 13 | הצפון החדש החלק הצפוני | 6.521e+07 | הרב צירלסון | 6106-307-5 | דירה בבית קומות | 2 | ראשונה | 45 | 3.6e+06 |  |  | 5.00008e+07 | POLYGON (( 180658.41000000 666777.19000000, 180673.00000000 666779.12000000, 180671.59000000 666790.38000000, 180657.00000000 666788.62000000, 180658.41000000 666777.19000000)) | 52349603 | תל אביב -יפו | 5000 | 117893 |
| {'y': 667044.31, 'x': 180596.09, 'geometryType': 'point'} | {'xmin': 180633.8, 'ymin': 667078.19, 'xmax': 180658.3, 'ymax': 667096.5} | 18/12/2021 | 2021-12-18T00:00:00 | הרב צירלסון 39 | הצפון החדש החלק הצפוני | 6.521e+07 | הרב צירלסון | 6212-1245-20 |  | 2 |  | 56 | 4.08e+06 |  |  | 5.00008e+07 | POLYGON (( 180596.09000000 667044.31000000, 180612.80000000 667046.38000000, 180612.09000000 667052.31000000, 180618.20000000 667053.12000000, 180614.00000000 667085.81000000, 180607.59000000 667084.88000000, 180611.50000000 667054.19000000, 180595.09000000 667052.12000000, 180596.09000000 667044.31000000)) | 52333507 | תל אביב -יפו | 5000 | 109293 |
| {'y': 666911.19, 'x': 180668.5, 'geometryType': 'point'} | {'xmin': 180633.8, 'ymin': 667078.19, 'xmax': 180658.3, 'ymax': 667096.5} | 18/12/2021 | 2021-12-18T00:00:00 | הרב צירלסון 22 | הצפון החדש החלק הצפוני | 6.521e+07 | הרב צירלסון | 6106-327-7 |  | 4 |  | 104 | 743669 |  |  | 5.00008e+07 | POLYGON (( 180668.50000000 666911.19000000, 180690.59000000 666915.38000000, 180688.80000000 666924.88000000, 180666.70000000 666920.81000000, 180668.50000000 666911.19000000)) | 52085187 | תל אביב -יפו | 5000 | 76582 |
| {'y': 666911.19, 'x': 180668.5, 'geometryType': 'point'} | {'xmin': 180633.8, 'ymin': 667078.19, 'xmax': 180658.3, 'ymax': 667096.5} | 17/11/2021 | 2021-11-17T00:00:00 | הרב צירלסון 22 | הצפון החדש החלק הצפוני | 6.521e+07 | הרב צירלסון | 6106-327-6 |  | 3 | ראשונה | 93 | 285000 |  |  | 5.00008e+07 | POLYGON (( 180668.50000000 666911.19000000, 180690.59000000 666915.38000000, 180688.80000000 666924.88000000, 180666.70000000 666920.81000000, 180668.50000000 666911.19000000)) | 52085187 | תל אביב -יפו | 5000 | 76582 |

Comment: I try to do the same on another website with better real estate DATA but somehow it dosent work my new "payload" is wrong.  `url = "https://www.nadlan.gov.il/Nadlan.REST/Main/GetAssestAndDeals"`